# getting contents within class using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get the price of an item ($4.99) using Beautiful Soup from a website and am able to retrieve the following:

```
tag= soup.findAll("div", class_='prod-PriceHero')

[<div class="prod-PriceHero"><span class="hide-content display-inline-block-m"><span class="display-inline-block arrange-fit Price Price--stylized u-textColor" data-tl-id="Price-ProductOffer"><span><span class="Price-currency" content="USD" itemprop="priceCurrency">$</span><span class="Price-characteristic" content="4.99" itemprop="price">4</span><span class="Price-mark">.</span><span class="Price-mantissa">99</span></span></span></span><span class="hide-content-m"><span class="display-inline-block arrange-fit Price u-textColor" data-tl-id="Price-ProductOffer"><span><span class="Price-currency">$</span><span class="Price-characteristic">4</span><span class="Price-mark">.</span><span class="Price-mantissa">99</span></span></span></span></div>]
```

From here I've tried using the following code:

```
soup=bs(tag,'lxml')
txt=soup.get_text()
print(txt)
```

but get the following error:  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.

Is there any easy way to extract the $4.99 value from this?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the span by `data-tl-id` attribute and get all the text under it by `.text`

```
spans = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-tl-id":"Price-ProductOffer"})
[span.text for span in spans]
```

out:

```
['$4.99', '$4.99']
```